# Simple regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file with two types of lines.
One type looks like:

```
'6-digit-primary-id','6-digit-secondary-id',subject,author,text
```

The other is just words with no specific pattern.
In the former case, I want to know the primary id along with the text and in the latter I want to get the words.
What I've tried:

```
PATTERN = r'[1-9]{6},[1-9]{6},?*,?*,*'
match = re.match(PATTERN,input_line)
if match:
    primary_id = match.group()[0]
    text = match.group()[7]
else:
    text = input_line
```

But obviously I'm doing something wrong (getting 'invalid syntax')

Can anyone please point me to the right direction?

Comment: What does it mean for you `?` in `r'[1-9]{6},[1-9]{6},?*,?*,*'` ?

Comment: Also - what do you expect `match.group()[7]` to be doing exactly? You don't have *any* groups in your pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?` has a special meaning in regex patterns. It (greedily) matches 0 or 1 of the preceding regex. So `,?` matches a comma or no comma. `,?*` raises a `sre_compile.error`.

Perhaps you intended `.` instead of `?`. It matches any character except a newline (unless the re.DOTALL flag is specified).

```
PATTERN = r'(\d{6}),(\d{6}),(.*?),(.*?),(.*)'
match = re.match(PATTERN, input_line)
if match:
    primary_id = match.group(1)
    text = match.group(5)
else:
    text = input_line
```

---

Some other suggestions:

- You can use `\d` to specify the character pattern `[0-9]`. Note that this is adding `0` to your character class. (I assume that is okay). If not you can stick with `[1-9]{6}`.
- If you put groups in your regex pattern, then you can specify the
  parts using `match.group(num)` instead of `match.group()[num]`. (And it looks like you want `match.group(5)` rather than `match.group()[7]`.)
- The pattern `.*` matches as many characters as possible. `.*?`
  matches non-greedily. You need to match non-greedily for the subject and author patterns, lest they expand to match the remainder of the entire line.
- An alternative to `.*?` here would be `[^,]*`. This matches 0-or-more
  characters other than a comma.

  ```
  PATTERN = r'(\d{6}),(\d{6}),([^,]*),([^,]*),(.*)'
  ```

Answer (score 1):

In Regular Expressions, `*` means no, one or more occurrence of the previous character and `?` means no or one occurrence of the previous character. So `?*` is not a valid expression. You are probably mixing with the `.*?` operation which means "any character no, one or more time but match the less possible" (non-greedy).

You probably want

```py
PATTERN = r'[1-9]{6},[1-9]{6},.*?,.*?,.*'
```